# Spring Boot ActiveMQ embedded Broker

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

I am using Spring Boot with embedded Broker as below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfig {

    @Bean
    public BrokerService brokerService() throws Exception {
        BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
        broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
        broker.setPersistent(false);
        return broker;
    }
}
```

How can I do, if I want to detect when a client connected?

Comment: What do u mean by 'client' here ?

Comment: Who connect to the broker ?

Comment: Please refer http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html